# focus on last input ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, input, focus, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have been looking at a lot of focus directives, especially those posted [here](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/Adding-row-ngrepeat-model-How-4896676.S.5860144936430632961).

But none seem to work for my scenario. I have a tabset and a table inside with an `ng-repeat` that creates rows with inputs on it. The way I create them is using `ng-blur` at the end of the last row checkbox so the `ng-blur` fires the `addNewRow` method. What I want is to focus the first input on the newly created row but the focus goes to the browser search bar instead.

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonathanPinzonM/1ps7fddv/) to show the problem using a directive from the first posted [link](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/Adding-row-ngrepeat-model-How-4896676.S.5860144936430632961).

I tested this directive:

```
soccerApp.directive('setfocus', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var focus = !! attrs.setfocus && !attrs.setfocus.replace(/true/, '');
            if (focus === true) {
                //alert(element);
                element[0].focus();
            }
        }
    };
});
```

and the `element[0].focus();` actually fires when I create a new row but doesn't set the focus.

Can someone please take a look and tell me what could be wrong?

**NOTE:** The idea is to use the TAB key to loop through the inputs until the last one.

Comment: Your fiddle works fine for me.

Comment: when you create a new row you get the focus on the fisrt input?

Comment: When I click on a checkbox, and then I click somewhere else on the page, a new row is created with the focus on the first input

Comment: tried with explorer and chrome and same thing , if i step in the first row and tab through the end it works just fine, but when im at the last row the focus keeps going to the browser search bar , thats odd

Comment: the idea is to use the TAB key. did you try it like that?

Comment: The problem is that, at the moment you "tab" from the last input, your browser sets the focus out of the page. So you don't have any control on it anymore. I don't know if it's possible to override that without creating a fake invisible input below to keep the focus into the page

Comment: thank you Deblaton Jean-Philippe you are totally right, i added this  <a href="javascrip:;" id="bottom"></a>  at the bottom after my table and it actually work perfect. thank you a lot i was missing that point  i was going crazy with this.

Answer (score 0):

As Deblaton Jean-Philippe pointed out

> The problem is that, at the moment you "tab" from the last input, your browser sets the focus out of the page. So you don't have any control on it anymore. I don't know if it's possible to override that without creating a fake invisible input below to keep the focus into the page

i was missing a fake input so i added  a fake `<a href="javascrip:;" id="bottom"></a>` at the bottom after my table and it worked